# what is meaning of following quote?

Tags: quotes

A programmer started to cuss,

Because getting to sleep was a fuss.

As he lay there in bed,

Looping ’round in his head,

Was: while(!asleep()) sheep++;

I don't know where to put this query so I put it here

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about explaining a programmer joke.

Comment: @tchrist:  Software and those who build it are so important and commonplace today, that perhaps programmers' lingo can be considered a dialect of English. (This site is produced by some very good programmers...)

Comment: @comeAndGo That's like saying that a lot of people speak French.  Hence, French should be incorporated into English.  Programmers write in *languages* not dialects... Oh, and tchrist *is* a programmer!

Comment: @DavidM - ridiculous discussion. We speak English in my shop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of verse is called a [limerick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerick_%28poetry%29)

> ...a short, humorous, often ribald or nonsense poem, especially one
>   in five-line anapestic meter with a strict rhyme scheme (AABBA), which
>   is sometimes obscene with humorous intent. The first two lines rhyme
>   with the last line and the third and fourth line rhyme, and they are
>   usually shorter. The form can be found in England as of the early
>   years of the 18th century. It was popularized by Edward Lear in the
>   19th century, although he did not use the term.

The last line ends *plus plus* which rhymes with *cuss* and *fuss*, and the humour comes from it being programming language.

Also, counting sheep in your head is supposed to be a way of falling asleep if you are having trouble.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(!asleep()) sheep++;
```

This means he was counting sheep and apparently couldn't fall asleep.

In programming, a 'while' loop goes on forever until some condition is no longer true. In this case, the condition is !asleep() which is a function call to check if he is sleeping or not. The '!' is a logic operator which means 'not'. Since he is still awake, asleep() returns false and the ! sign negates false, making it true. If he were asleep then asleep() would return true and the ! sign would flip that, making the condition in the while loop false and then break the loop.

Inside the loop, a sheep variable is being incremented by the ++ operator. So, the sheep variable may start at 1 and in each iteration the number is incremented by 1. ++ really means sheep = sheep + 1.

Comment: It might work better in binary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's better in the original [MIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIX).

Answer (score 1):

```
Looping ’round in his head,
Was: while(!asleep()) sheep++;
```

Translation:

```
He kept saying to himself,  
As long as I'm not asleep, I'll keep counting sheep.
```

Answer (score 1):

The last line

> Was: while(!asleep()) sheep++;

means

> Was: while not asleep increment sheep

the rhyme comes from asleep and sheep. It is a very simple loop; he is incrementing sheeps in his imagination so he can fall asleep.